# Drawable alignment with text in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I have problem with this:
[image: Back button with drawable left]

As you can see the back icon is not correctly with the back text.
It needs to be little bit downwards.

I've tried:

1. to change the drawable image, resizing it.
2. `padding` but it is not useful for this condition
3. to switch to `Button,Material button` but nothing works fine.

Here is my code(Design code):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_back"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textColor="@color/SkyBlue"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I need like this:(See that mailbox button)
[image: ios back button]

Note 1: This is just because my client have this kind of specific design.(IOS inspired).

Note 2: I know IOS design standards and android design are way different; also this design wont fit in android deign guidelines. But I can't do anything.

Comment: Better use a `ImageView` and a `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout`

Comment: @ADM Yes I thought of it... It is a very good idea but why we can't fully align in textview ..

Comment: The design u have added have Arrow height bigger than Text View even though u use bigger icon this can fail on some other resolution devices so its better to use above approach . I mean why make things complicated if there a better solution.

Comment: @ADM Thank... What if user tried to touch on icon.. I will have to write another onclick listerer or is it okey to leave it alone (too close to clickable text)

Comment: @ADM I also tried to adjust height.. making it smaller but is not working

Comment: You set click on the outer layout that is Linear layout . This will handle both views